# Post thumbnail not working when previewing post

Tags: post-thumbnails, previews

In my theme, thumbnails are working just fine for the most part. But when I preview a post by clicking the "Preview changes" button, about 3/4th of the thumbnails on the page are broken. When I test with `has_post_thumbnail()` or `get_post_thumbnail_id()`, nothing is returned indicating that no thumbnails are associated with the posts.

Again, the odd thing is everything works just fine on published posts. Any idea the cause?

Comment: Can you show me the "Live" post url and the "Preview" post url.

Comment: The "live" url is `https://domain.com/title/` and the "preview" url is `https://domain.com/?p=1337&preview=true`. Most of the thumbnails for related posts & sidebar widget posts are missing — they're not 404ing, they simply aren't returned.